# Toggle Class com Rolagem no Firefox

Tags: javascript, rolamento, firefox

Olá!
Tenho o seguinte código que por algum motivo funciona perfeitamente no Chrome, mas não no Firefox. Alguém poderia me ajudar a decifrar o porquê? Tendo em vista que ele já foi trabalhado para tentar se adaptar ao Firefox. Ainda sem sucesso.

```
<script>
var scrollVal = 0;
var mousewheelevt=(/Firefox/i.test(navigator.userAgent))? "DOMMouseScroll" : "mousewheel";
$(document).bind(mousewheelevt, function(e) {
    var offset = -1 * e.originalEvent.wheelDelta;
    if (mousewheelevt == "DOMMouseScroll"){
      offset = e.originalEvent.layerY - e.originalEvent.clientY;
    }
    scrollVal += offset;        
    if (scrollVal < 0) scrollVal = 0;
    console.log(scrollVal);        
    if (scrollVal == 0) {
        $('#projetos').addClass( "bottom");
    }else {
        $('#projetos').removeClass("bottom");
    }    
});
</script>
```

Comment: Realmente a minha resposta estava redundante, eu removi por isso

Comment: Uma dúvida, no Firefox, ele chega a entrar na função?

Comment: @RicardoPontual Me parece que sim, mas de uma maneira muito esquisita. Se eu mudo essa linha `if (scrollVal == 0) {` para `if (scrollVal > 1000) {`, depois de rolados 1000px, ele faz o que deveria fazer. Me parece que no firefox, o `scrollVal` só aumenta, enquanto no Chrome ele sobe e desce, como deveria.

Comment: Na linha `var offset = -1 * e.originalEvent.wheelDelta;` tente usar `detail` no lugar do `wheelDelta`. Tem uma diferença no jeito que os navegadores pegam esses valores.

Comment: Tentei e parou de aumentar o `scrollVal`, consequentemente não funcionou.

Comment: Pesquisando um pouco para tirar a dúvida sobre a compatibilidade, achei esse link, pode ser que te ajude a resolver: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/onmousewheel.shtml

Comment: @RicardoPontual Já até vi esse artigo. O problema é muito específico. Não sei porque no Firefox o `scrollVal` não desce...